# Problems with concatenating rows using pd.groupby().agg()

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

For example, let's say that I have the dataframe:

```
NAME = ['BOB', 'BOB', 'BOB', 'SUE', 'SUE', 'MARY', 'JOHN', 'JOHN', 'MARK', 'MARK', 'MARK', 'MARK']
    STATE = ['CA','CA','CA','DC','DC','PA','GA','GA','NY','NY','NY','NY']
    MAJOR = ['MARKETING','BUSINESS ADM',np.nan,'ECONOMICS','MATH','PSYCHOLOGY','HISTORY','BUSINESS ADM','MATH', 'MEDICAL SCIENCES',np.nan,np.nan]
    SCHOOL = ['UCLA','UCSB','CAL STATE','HARVARD','WISCONSIN','YALE','CHICAGO','MIT','UCSD','UCLA','CAL STATE','COMMUNITY']
    data = {'NAME':NAME, 'STATE':STATE,'MAJOR':MAJOR, 'SCHOOL':SCHOOL}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I am to concatenate rows with multiple unique values for the same name.

I tried:

```
  gr_columns = [x for x in df1.columns if x not in ['MAJOR','SCHOOL']]
    df1 = df1.groupby(gr_columns).agg(lambda col: '|'.join(col))
```

and expected

I am trying to concatenate rows in columns where the NAME field is the same. Conveniently, the STATE field is static for each NAME. I would like the output to look like:

| NAME | STATE | MAJOR | SCHOOL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BOB | CA | MARKETING,BUSINESS ADM | UCLA,UCSB,CAL STATE |
| SUE | DC | ECONOMICS,MATH | HARVARD,WISCONSIN |
| MARY | PA | PSYCHOLOGY | YALE |
| JOHN | GA | HISTORY,BUSINESS ADM | CHICAGO,MIT |
| MARK | NY | MATH,MEDICAL SCIENCES | UCSD,UCLA,CAL STATE,COMMUNITY |

but instead, I get a single column containing the concatenated schools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because your `np.nan` cannot be converted to str, so it is dropped automatically by pandas. You need to convert its type to str first:

```
df.groupby(['NAME', 'STATE']).agg(lambda x: ','.join(x.astype(str)))
```

To drop na and keep NAME and STATE as columns:

```
df.groupby(['NAME', 'STATE']).agg(lambda x: ','.join(x.dropna())).reset_index()
```

Comment: Thank you, that brought in the MAJOR column, but it still drops the NAME and STATE Columns. I know in SQL the group_concat function retains the group by columns. Is there a way to do that in python?

Comment: Is there a way to drop the nan instead of converting it to str?

Comment: the NAME and STATE columns are not droppped. They are turned into index. You could convert the index to columns by `df.reset_index()`.